# Appropriate formatting of NumPy dtypes for arrays within Structured Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, structured-array

I am trying to create a numpy structured array but I can't figure out the correct way to format my column titles/column types for arrays within arrays.  I keep getting the `setting an array element with a sequence` message, but I can convert the list into an unstructured array without a problem so the problem is in the formatting of the dtypes in the sub-arrays.

**Code**

```
#Number of People
numOfP=5
#Array of people's ids
ids=np.array(range(0,numOfP),dtype='int64')
#People object
temp=[];
peoType=np.dtype({
    'names':
    ['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'],
    'formats':
    ['int64','float64','float32','float32','object','object'],
    'aligned':True
});
#Populate people with attributes
for id in ids:
    temp.append([
        #0 - id
        id,
        #1 - people's value
        sts.lognorm.rvs(.5)*100000,
        #2 - people's ability
        (1/(sts.lognorm.rvs(.99)+1)),
        #3 - help needed
        ((sts.lognorm.rvs(.99))*100),
        #4 - people helped
#This is where the problem is, if I get rid of these arrays, and the associated dtypes, there are no errors
        np.zeros(numOfP),
        #5 - people who helped you
        np.zeros(numOfP)
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ])
peoType
temp
#doing np.array(temp), without the dtype works
temp=np.asarray(temp)      #doesn't change anything
temp
peo=np.array(temp,peoType) #where things break
```

**dtype**

```
{'names': ['id', 'value', 'ability', 'helpNeeded', 'helpOut', 'helpIn'],
 'formats': ['int64', 'float64', 'float32', 'float32', 'object', 'object'],
 'aligned': True}
```

**Error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
e:\xampp\htdocs\Math2Code\cooperate.py in 
     52     ])
     53 peoType
---> 54 peo=np.array(temp,peoType)

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

**Contents of `temp` List**

```
[[0,
  86381.14170220899,
  0.12974876676966007,
  49.537761763004056,
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
 [1,
  95532.94886721167,
  0.3886984384013719,
  49.9244719570076,
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
 [2,
  53932.09250542036,
  0.6518993291826463,
  92.72979425242384,
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
 [3,
  161978.14156816195,
  0.49130827569636754,
  56.44742176255372,
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
 [4,
  38679.21128565417,
  0.6979042712239539,
  132.35562828412765,
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]]
```

**Contents of `temp` after converted to a unstructured array**

```
array([[0, 119297.86954924025, 0.38806815548557444, 487.4877681755314,
        array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
       [1, 75215.69897153028, 0.5387632600167043, 83.27487024641633,
        array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
       [2, 88986.345811315, 0.2533847055636237, 48.52795408229029,
        array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
       [3, 80539.81607335186, 0.27683829962996226, 226.25682883690638,
        array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
       [4, 40429.11615682778, 0.5748035151329913, 226.69671215072958,
        array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]],
      dtype=object)
```

**Output of the peoType np.dtype variable when used in a 2x2 np.zeros array:**

Input

```
np.zeros(2, peoType)
```

Output

```
array([(0, 0., 0., 0., 0, 0), (0, 0., 0., 0., 0, 0)],
      dtype={'names':['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8','<f4','<f4','O','O'], 'offsets':[0,8,16,20,24,32], 'itemsize':40, 'aligned':True})
```

*Why the rows rapped in tuples????*

Comment: When used with a compound dtype, `temp` needs to be a list of **tuples**.  Look at `x=np.zeros(2, peoType)` to see what that input should look like.  The display mimics the input, much as the nesting of lists of a unstructured array does.  Experiment with making a simpler structured array.

Comment: Thanks, that proved somewhat productive, at least now I know what this dtype is producing, but why do there need to be tuples involved?  I did not enclose my dtype dict in them.  I have added the output of this to my question.

Comment: Each tuple is a `record`, the elements that correspond to the fields of the `dtype`.  The `numpy` developers chose this tuple convention for structured arrays.  Evidently you read enough about structured arrays to create a relatively complex `dtype`, but missed the part about setting data values.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason you cannot create arrays using only arrays ‍♂️.  Switching `temp.append([ ... ])` to `temp.append(( ... ))` solved the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: The structured docs mention a `recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured` function

Comment: It was late last night when I wrote that switching to making `temp` a tuple solved the problem.  I realized that tuples were not going to work after all because they cannot be changed.  I needed to make all my vars in the temp list `np.array`s and then surround those with a tuple or else the model I am working on wouldn't work.  Seems kind of pointless to need to make a `list` a `tuple` in order to convert it to an `array`. I'll look into `unstructured_to_structured`.

Comment: Why would you need to change the tuples?  They aren't preserved as such in the structured array.   `np.array([tuple(sublist) for sublist in alist], dtype)` creates the necessary list of tuples from a list of lists.  I don't think the `unstructured...` function will work with your dtype that includes object fields.

Comment: Tuples are immutable – the whole point of converting the list to an `np.array` was to then be able to do math to the cells in the array.  If I keep things tuples, doing operations on them has no affect.  It is interesting that trying to do operations while keeping the cells tuples does not raise an error, it just doesn't change the values.

Comment: I don't know what math or changes you are trying to do.  Immutability of tuples isn't an issue here, at least not when creating a structured array.  A structured array does not store the tuples or reference them at all (any more than it stores the nested lists of a 2d array).  I'd suggest a new question with examples of the problem operations.

Answer (score 1):

Too big for a comment, but this demonstrates the tuple for input to produce the structured array.  If vals is a list, then you will get an error.  Sample, below is using one of your inputs.

```
vals = (2,
  53932.09250542036,
  0.6518993291826463,
  92.72979425242384,
  np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
  np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))

dt={'names':['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8','<f4','<f4','O','O']}

a = np.asarray(vals, dtype=dt)

a
array((2,  53932.09,  0.65,  92.73, array([ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00]), array([ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00])),
      dtype=[('id', '<i8'), ('value', '<f8'), ('ability', '<f4'), ('helpNeeded', '<f4'), ('helpOut', 'O'), ('helpIn', 'O')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compound dtype:

```
In [33]: peoType=np.dtype({
    ...:     'names':
    ...:     ['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'],
    ...:     'formats':
    ...:     ['int64','float64','float32','float32','object','object'],
    ...:     'aligned':True
    ...: })
```

A sample structured array with that dtype:

```
In [34]: arr = np.zeros(2, peoType)
In [35]: arr
Out[35]: 
array([(0, 0., 0., 0., 0, 0), (0, 0., 0., 0., 0, 0)],
      dtype={'names':['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8','<f4','<f4','O','O'], 'offsets':[0,8,16,20,24,32], 'itemsize':40, 'aligned':True})
In [36]: arr['id']
Out[36]: array([0, 0])
In [37]: arr['helpOut']
Out[37]: array([0, 0], dtype=object)
```

`()` is used to mark individual records.  This is a 1d array, with records, not rows and columns.  The notation tries to make this clear.  Operations like `reshape` and `broadcasting` don't cross that `record` boundary.

Make your `temp` list:

```
In [39]: array = np.array
In [40]: temp=[[0,
    ...:   86381.14170220899,
    ...:   0.12974876676966007,
    ...:   49.537761763004056,
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
    ...:  [1,
    ...:   95532.94886721167,
    ...:   0.3886984384013719,
    ...:   49.9244719570076,
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
    ...:  [2,
    ...:   53932.09250542036,
    ...:   0.6518993291826463,
    ...:   92.72979425242384,
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
    ...:  [3,
    ...:   161978.14156816195,
    ...:   0.49130827569636754,
    ...:   56.44742176255372,
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
    ...:  [4,
    ...:   38679.21128565417,
    ...:   0.6979042712239539,
    ...:   132.35562828412765,
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
    ...:   array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])]]
```

Make a structured array from the list - first converting it into a list of tuples, as required by structured array:

```
In [42]: arr = np.array([tuple(row) for row in temp], peoType)
In [43]: arr
Out[43]: 
array([(0,  86381.14170221, 0.12974876,  49.53776 , array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
       (1,  95532.94886721, 0.38869843,  49.924473, array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
       (2,  53932.09250542, 0.65189934,  92.7298  , array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
       (3, 161978.14156816, 0.49130827,  56.447422, array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])),
       (4,  38679.21128565, 0.6979043 , 132.35562 , array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]))],
      dtype={'names':['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8','<f4','<f4','O','O'], 'offsets':[0,8,16,20,24,32], 'itemsize':40, 'aligned':True})
In [44]: arr['helpOut']
Out[44]: 
array([array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])], dtype=object)
```

The object dtype field is a 1d array of objects - arrays.

If all those object fields contained the same size arrays, we could replace them with multi-item fields:

```
In [50]: dt=np.dtype({
    ...:     'names':
    ...:     ['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'],
    ...:     'formats':
    ...:     ['int64','float64','float32','float32','5float','5float'],
    ...:     'aligned':True
    ...: })
In [51]: arr = np.array([tuple(row) for row in temp], dt)
In [52]: arr
Out[52]: 
array([(0,  86381.14170221, 0.12974876,  49.53776 , [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (1,  95532.94886721, 0.38869843,  49.924473, [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (2,  53932.09250542, 0.65189934,  92.7298  , [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (3, 161978.14156816, 0.49130827,  56.447422, [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
       (4,  38679.21128565, 0.6979043 , 132.35562 , [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.], [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])],
      dtype={'names':['id','value','ability','helpNeeded','helpOut','helpIn'], 'formats':['<i8','<f8','<f4','<f4',('<f8', (5,)),('<f8', (5,))], 'offsets':[0,8,16,20,24,64], 'itemsize':104, 'aligned':True})
In [53]: arr['helpOut']
Out[53]: 
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Now that field produces a 2d array.

Comment: I just changed `temp` to a tuple (changed `temp=[...]` to `temp=(..)`) and made everything in the tuple an array.  I still don't under stand why I need to do that though.

Comment: Notice in `Out[52]` that the display has nested `[]` and `()`.  That nesting isn't just random.  It's designed to convey useful information about shapes and fields.  They aren't interchangeable.  You can't `reshape` a 1d array with 3 fields into a (n,3) array.  The developers decided that it made most sense to expect a matching input, using nested lists and tuples.